# On the second click, picture seems unresponsive. (OpenCv-Python)

Tags: python, image, function, numpy, opencv

When I click on the picture twice, I want it to save two rgb codes as `a` and `b`, and then the code should stop. When I try to do this, I save the rgb colors that I first clicked on but on the second click then my picture not responding. How do I fix it?

My Code :

```py
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    
    def mouse(event,x,y,flags,param):
        global a
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: 
            colorsb = image[y,x,0]
            colorsg = image[y,x,1]
            colorsr = image[y,x,2]
            colors = image[y,x]
            
            print("Red: ",colorsr)
            print("Green: ",colorsg)
            print("Blue: ",colorsb)
            print("BRG : ",colors)
            print("Coordinates of pixel: X: ",x,"Y: ",y)
    
            
            #I want to receive 1 more input.
            a = input(colors)
    
            
    image = cv2.imread("x.jpg")
    cv2.namedWindow("Image")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse)
    
    
    while(1):
        cv2.imshow("Image",image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
    print(a)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[My Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPyl7.jpg)

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RahGA.jpg)

Comment: you call `input()`. that requires you to type stuff on the terminal... and if you don't, it'll just be **stuck** there. hence the GUI becomes unresponsive. **do not** block the GUI code. don't read from the terminal while you have a GUI running.